# how to get VARCHAR2(26 CHAR) to display as date time in query result

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

[image]

My data included both string and numeric variable. and the data type is "VARCHAR2"  in the subset of result i am looking for, all of them time stamps are in numbers.  how do i get the query (on sql developer/oracle) to disply in readable date/time

very new to sql so please help!

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR2(26 Char),GETDATE(med.poetimestamp),108)
```

> ORA-00936: missing expression
>   00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"

Comment: From the error message that looks like Oracle and not SQL server. Can you edit your tags if so

Comment: `varchar2` also isn't a valid data type in SQL Server, as I've removed the tag.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Why would you try to convert a string to a string to display it?

Comment: the data contains both: date/time in 2000-03-20:23:12:29.176262 and 991010049

Comment: Does `991010049` represent a date or time value, and if so what date or time does `991010049` represent?

Answer (score 2):

Your poetimestamp column seems being of type Unix Timestamp from the picture, so can use the following select statement :

```
select date'1970-01-01' + m.poetimestamp / 86400
  from med m;
```

`convert()` and `getdate()` function are special to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You said "the data contains both: date/time in 2000-03-20:23:12:29.176262 and 991010049". You have to explicitly code for both cases. If there are other cases, you have to code for each one.

I find it strange that there is a colon between the date part and the time part. Is this for real or is it a type? I am assuming it is for real, but you can change the format yourself I hope.

```
with data(x) as (
  select '2000-03-20:23:12:29.176262' from dual
  union all
  select '991010049' from dual
)
select case 
  when substr(x,5,1) = '-' then to_timestamp(x, 'yyyy-mm-dd:hh24:mi:ss.ff')
  else cast(date '1970-01-01' + numtodsinterval(x, 'second') as timestamp)
end ts
from data;

TS                           
-----------------------------
2000-03-20 23:12:29,176262000
2001-05-28 00:34:09,000000000
```

Best regards,
Stew Ashton